# Generating correlated random variables with discrete distribution

Tags: probability, correlation

I would like to find a simple way to generate two correlated random variables under the condition that each r.v has a same discrete distribution (for example Bernoulli distribution) [This link provides a solution but I wonder if there is something more straightforward.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19406/constructing-bernoulli-random-variables-with-prescribed-correlation)

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

When you are dealing with two discrete random variables you can calculate the conditional probabilities and simulate directly from there.  The following doesn't require that the two variables $X$, and $Y$ have the same distribution, just that they both have $n$ outcomes (for simplicity of exposition).

Whatever your correlation is, use that to determine the joint density of the two random variables.  This is an array of numbers
     $$P(X = x, Y = y) = p_{xy}$$

Now calculate the marginal density of $X$ and the conditional density of $Y$:
     $$P(X = x) = \sum_y p_{xy}$$
     $$P(Y = y | X = x) = p_{xy} / P(X = x)$$

To simulate, first choose a value for $X$ using the distribution $X = x$.  Then to find $Y$, choose from the distribution $P(Y = y | X = x)$ that conditions on the outcome you saw for $X$.

If your discrete distribution is Bernoulli then your correlation will directly define the joint distribution as follows:

Suppose $P(X = 1) = p$ and $P(X = 0) = 1-p$. Then 
$$\rho = \frac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]}{\sqrt{E[X^2] - E[X]^2}\sqrt{E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2}} = \frac{P(X = 1, Y = 1) - p^2}{p - p^2}$$
Now can solve for $P(X = 1, Y = 1)$ to find:
$$P(X = 1, Y = 1) = p^2 + \rho p(1 - p)$$

For the general distribution you can use the above definition of correlation to fix the cross moment $E[XY]$.
$$E[XY] = E[X]^2 + \rho\left(E[X^2] - E[X]^2\right)$$
Beyond that, if there are more than two outcomes, you will have many degrees of freedom in the joint density, any choice of which will give you the correlated outcomes you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but how can I determine the joint density knowing the correlation ?

Comment: @Dark  You'll need to specify more about the distributions in general since correlation alone won't define them.  e.g. A jointly normal distribution for $(X, Y)$ can have a particular correlation $\rho$ between its two random variables which have the same marginals, but they can have any $\mu, \sigma$.  If by Bernoulli you mean and outcome of zero and one, then there is only one parameter $P(X = 1) = p$ and that will be uniquely determined by the correlation.  Were you looking for the formula that relates correlation to $p$ for the Bernoulli situation?

Comment: I have a given correlation $\rho$ and a given discrete law. I would like to generate two correlated r.v that follow this law with a correlation of $\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest example I can think of:

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be iid Bernoulli with success probability $\theta = 1/2.$ Then $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$ and $Y_2 = X_2 + X_3$ are both
$Binom(2, 1/2),$ but they are correlated.

Because you mention 'generating' here is a simple simulation in R:

```
 x1 = rbinom(10^6, 1, 1/2)
 x2 = rbinom(10^6, 1, 1/2)
 x3 = rbinom(10^6, 1, 1/2)
 y1 = x1 + x2;  y2 = x2 + x3
 cor(y1,y2)
 ## 0.5007598
```

Many possible variations with $W_1 = X_1 + aX_2$ and $W_2 = aX_2 + X_3$, for various values of $a.$

Comment: Thanks. I would however like to find a more general way for any target discrete law.

Comment: @Dark: New level of Question here: Same basic method works for Poisson and Geometric-Negative Binomial families. What sort of generality do you seek? Do you have examples? Is method of other Answer helpful?